# Update dataframe rows trough loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe and I want to create some new columns that contain the growth of the original columns.

First, I append the new columns to the dataframe, filling them with NaN values.

Then, for every row I check if the previous row corresponds to the previous year, and if it does I want to fill the new column with the growth of the variable. Otherwise I just leave the NaN value.

Here is my code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if df.loc[index,'year'] == df.loc[index - 1, 'year'] + 1 and df.loc[index,'name'] == df.loc[index - 1, 'name']:
       df.loc[index,k:] = (df.loc[index,1:k-1]/df.loc[index-1,1:k-1]) - 1
```

Where k is the column index of the first new "growth" column that I created.

The problem with this code is that it leaves the new columns with NaN values, without making any change. Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: something with `df.merge(df.assign(year=df.year+1), on = 'year'...)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have multiple observations (companies) for every year, I'm not sure that would work. The dataframe has been sorted initially by company name and then by year, and in the if condition there's also an and condition that the company name of the row is equal to the company name in the previous row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df.sort_values('year', inplace = True)
growth_cols = [<your-growth-cols>]
new_cols = [x + "_growth" for x in growth_cols]
growth_df = df[growth_cols] / df[growth_cols].shift(1)
growth_df.rename(columns = dict(zip(growth_cols, new_cols)), inplace = True)
df = pd.concat([df, growth_df], axis =1)
df['gap'] = df.year.diff()
for col in new_cols:
    df[col] = df[col] * df['gap']
    df[col].replace(0, np.nan, inplace = True)
df.drop('gap', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

EDIT (based on updated question):

You would need to change the line

```py
df['gap'] = df.year.diff()
```

to:

```py
df['gap'] = df.groupby('name').diff()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bishwarup.  I can't just shift the whole dataframe and divide because all the rows are not relative to consecutive years. Moreover, for the same year I have multiple companies (column: 'name') so before filling the new row if have to check that the company name is the same.The dataframe has been sorted initially by company name and then by year, and in the if condition of the loop there's also an and condition that the company name of the row is equal to the company name in the previous row. I updated the code in the question to be more clear.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the additional inputs. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Should work. Couple of issues: I think that the updated line should be: df['gap'] = df.groupby('name').year.diff(), right? And also, only the values of ratios['gap'] that are equal to 1 should be kept before running the loop I guess.

Comment: That’s right, I shall edit once I am back on my desk. Also, before running the last for loop, you may choose to retain the rows corresponding to year = 1 or just leave it be as for any other row the growths will be set to NaN. Please consider upvoting if you found my code helpful. Thank you :)